# Symfony 2.1 permissions, unit test, session

Tags: php, unit-testing, session, jenkins, symfony-2.1

I am creating application based on `Symfony 2.1`. I write code locally, upload it on server and then run unit tests. When every test pass I run `Jenkins` job to check code style and etc.

Recently I encounter a very strange problem. Unit test pass on my development environment but when I run `Jenkins`, test failures because there is exception says `Headers already sent`.
I use flashBag for flash messages. I try to remove it but another test crash with same exception where there is nothing related with session. Also there are problem with permissions. Once a while I get exception from profiler says `ErrorException: Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in`. I tried with umask in `app*.php` but no result.

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In your context, 'Headers already sent' sounds like some class is throwing an exception or printing an error message, before you try to send headers. That your test succeeds on dev but fails later on in the process probably means it's an environmental problem causing the trouble.

As you mention a permission error in your profiler, couldn't the next scenario be plausible:

- Permissions on dev are correct.
- Permissions on test (or wherever you're building to) are incorrect.
- Something fails because of the lack of right permissions.
- That something prints an error message accordingly.
- You get the Header already sent-message.

It's a longshot, but you didn't give alot of information.